# Form validation change input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Javascript regualar expression for form validation in my project.Once the validation is completed without any error and while clicking submit button the form should submit and I need to change the submit value to 'please wait..'.
I have tried two methods.
Method 1:By changing the submit value
Method 2:Hide/show method using jquery
Both the methods are not working and i couldn't find the error to.Can anyone help me with this?

```js
/*
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  var uluru = {lat: 12.991011, lng: 77.721225};
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 10, center: uluru});
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
  */
  

function pagetest(){
 var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
  var filt =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (!name.match(filt)){
   document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML='Name should not contain any number or special characters';
   document.getElementById("nameerror").style.color='red';
   }
  else{
   document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML='valid name';
   document.getElementById("nameerror").style.color='green';
  }
    
 var number=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
  if(number.length!=10)
    {
   document.getElementById("mobile").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("moberror").innerHTML="Number should be exactly 10 digits and not less than or more than that";
   document.getElementById("moberror").style.color='red';
    }
  else
    {
   document.getElementById("mobile").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("moberror").innerHTML="valid number";
   document.getElementById("moberror").style.color='green';
    }

    
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$/;
  if (!filter.test(email)) {
   
   document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML="Please provide a valid email address";
   document.getElementById("emailerror").style.color="red"; 
   }
  else{

   document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML='valid email address';
   document.getElementById("emailerror").style.color='green';
  }
     
    
 var country= document.getElementById("country").value;
  var filt =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (!country.match(filt)) {
   document.getElementById("country").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("countryerror").innerHTML='country should not contain any number or special characters';
   document.getElementById("countryerror").style.color='red';
   }
  else{

   document.getElementById("country").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("countryerror").innerHTML='Valid Country name';
   document.getElementById("countryerror").style.color='green';
  }
    
 var city= document.getElementById("city").value;
  var filt =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (!city.match(filt)) {
   document.getElementById("city").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("cityerror").innerHTML='city should not contain any number or special characters';
   document.getElementById("cityerror").style.color='red';
   }
  else{
   document.getElementById("city").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("cityerror").innerHTML='Valid city name';
   document.getElementById("cityerror").style.color='green';
  }
    
   /* var reg = /[^A-Za-z]/;
    if ((reg.test(query) == false) && (query ==""))
    {
                document.getElementById('query').style.borderColor="red";
                document.getElementById('queryerror').innerHTML="This field is required";
    }
    else{
     document.getElementById("query").style.borderColor="green";
     document.getElementById("queryerror").innerHTML ="";
    }*/
   
 var security = document.getElementById("security").value;
 var securitycode = document.getElementById("securitycode").innerHTML;
  if(security ==securitycode){
   document.getElementById("security").style.borderColor="";
   document.getElementById("codeerror").innerHTML="Code matched";
   document.getElementById("codeerror").style.color='green';
  } 
  else{
   document.getElementById("security").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("codeerror").innerHTML="Code didn't match or emplty";
   document.getElementById("codeerror").style.color='red';
   var val =Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
   document.getElementById("securitycode").innerHTML =val;
   security.focus;
  }
  
 if( (name!="") && (email!="")  && (number!="") && (country!="") && (city!="") && (security!="")) 
    {
     //alert("ok");
     document.getElementById("form_id").submit();//submit() is a predefined function in js. 
          //document.getElementById("").innerHTML='Please wait..';
    }
 }
 
   /*$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
     if(validationIsTrue()){
      (":button").css('display':'none');
      ('#Button1').css('display':'block');
     }
     else{
      return false;
     }
   });
   });
   
   $("#form_id").on("submit", function(e){
   var $this = $(this);
   if(this.checkValidity()) {
      e.preventDefault();
   alert('ok');
      //$this.parents(".form-wrap").hide();
      //$(".success-msg").removeClass("hidden")
   }
});
   
 */
```

```css
.iframe-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* Ratio 16:9 ( 100%/16*9 = 56.25% ) */
}
.iframe-container > *{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Demo styles */
.iframe-container{
margin-top:50px;
width:100%;
} 
/*form */
 .content{
 background-image:url("contact-us (1).jpg");
 min-height: 380px;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 400px rgba(185, 212, 212, 0.35);
  /* Needed to position the navbar */
  
}
.form-group{
 color:white;
}
.no-border {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none; /* You may want to include this as bootstrap applies these styles too */
}
.contact{
 color:#BF2626;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-top:25px;
}
input,textarea{
 margin-left:5px;
}

input:focus{
 background-color:#b9dbe2;
 color:black;
}
label{
 color:black;
 margin-top:4px;
}
.code{
 color:black;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-left:7px;
}
h3{
 margin-left:-80px;
}
#securitycode{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="formvali.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
  
 </head>
 <body onsubmit="loginload()">
 <div class="col-sm-12 content">
 <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
 <h2 class="text-center">
  Fill out this form and we will get back to you<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>
 </h2>
 
 
   <!-- <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7245780.082381814!2d-88.29713116153964!3d27.53212533124578!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88c1766591562abf%3A0xf72e13d35bc74ed0!2sFlorida!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1470659148428" class="img-responsive" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 -->
 <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Bangalore Office</strong></h3>
  <iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=12.987510,77.620491 &z=13&output=embed" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
 <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Kerala Office</strong></h3>
 <iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=9.988126,76.295285 &z=13&output=embed" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
   </div>
 
 
 <div class="col-sm-6" style="line-height:1.45;">
  <h1 class="text-center contact">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Us</h1>
  <form action="#" method="POST" id="form_id" name="myform">
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
     <i id="nameerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
   
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>Mobile</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" id="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number">
     <i id="moberror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
   
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label style="margin-left:0px;">Email </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">  
     <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control"placeholder="Enter Your Email Id">
      <i id="emailerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
     
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>Country</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" id="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Country Name">
     <i id="countryerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
  
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>City</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control"placeholder="Enter Your City Name">
     <i id="cityerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
   
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>Query</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="query"placeholder="Enter Your Query here(optional)"></textarea>
     <i id="queryerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <span class="code"></strong>Security Code <span id="securitycode"></span></span>
     <input type="number" id="security" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the security code">
     <i id="codeerror"></i><br>
     <div class="form-group text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="sub" value="Submit" onclick="pagetest()"/>
      <button id="Button1" style="display:none;">Please wait..</button>
      
     </div>
      
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  
  <script>
  
   var val =Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
   document.getElementById("securitycode").innerHTML = val;
  </script>
  <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXRmYpTXDBP7vdQ-2fy11OqoKGUuGfcxI&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please include your code so we can actually help you?

Comment: Yes I have included my code.

Comment: Is the form submitting to itself? When a form is submitted everything on the page halts, all gif animation, all JavaScript and you are redirected to the page specified in action. In your case you are submitting to itself so the page refreshes.

Comment: Actually I just specified '#' in form action to validate.

Comment: so basically you want to change the value in submit button , right?

Comment: No,My problem is when I'm submitting the form,I need to change the submit value to please wait after the validation.Either form validation is doing or value of submit is changing.I need both to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function pagetest(){
 var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
  var filt =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (!name.match(filt)){
   document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML='Name should not contain any number or special characters';
   document.getElementById("nameerror").style.color='red';
   }
  else{
   document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML='valid name';
   document.getElementById("nameerror").style.color='green';
  }
    
 var number=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
  if(number.length!=10)
    {
   document.getElementById("mobile").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("moberror").innerHTML="Number should be exactly 10 digits and not less than or more than that";
   document.getElementById("moberror").style.color='red';
    }
  else
    {
   document.getElementById("mobile").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("moberror").innerHTML="valid number";
   document.getElementById("moberror").style.color='green';
    }

    
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$/;
  if (!filter.test(email)) {
   
   document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML="Please provide a valid email address";
   document.getElementById("emailerror").style.color="red"; 
   }
  else{

   document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML='valid email address';
   document.getElementById("emailerror").style.color='green';
  }
     
    
 var country= document.getElementById("country").value;
  var filt =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (!country.match(filt)) {
   document.getElementById("country").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("countryerror").innerHTML='country should not contain any number or special characters';
   document.getElementById("countryerror").style.color='red';
   }
  else{

   document.getElementById("country").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("countryerror").innerHTML='Valid Country name';
   document.getElementById("countryerror").style.color='green';
  }
    
 var city= document.getElementById("city").value;
  var filt =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (!city.match(filt)) {
   document.getElementById("city").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("cityerror").innerHTML='city should not contain any number or special characters';
   document.getElementById("cityerror").style.color='red';
   }
  else{
   document.getElementById("city").style.borderColor="green";
   document.getElementById("cityerror").innerHTML='Valid city name';
   document.getElementById("cityerror").style.color='green';
  }
    
   /* var reg = /[^A-Za-z]/;
    if ((reg.test(query) == false) && (query ==""))
    {
                document.getElementById('query').style.borderColor="red";
                document.getElementById('queryerror').innerHTML="This field is required";
    }
    else{
     document.getElementById("query").style.borderColor="green";
     document.getElementById("queryerror").innerHTML ="";
    }*/
   
 var security = document.getElementById("security").value;
 var securitycode = document.getElementById("securitycode").innerHTML;
  if(security ==securitycode){
   document.getElementById("security").style.borderColor="";
   document.getElementById("codeerror").innerHTML="Code matched";
   document.getElementById("codeerror").style.color='green';
  } 
  else{
   document.getElementById("security").style.borderColor="red";
   document.getElementById("codeerror").innerHTML="Code didn't match or emplty";
   document.getElementById("codeerror").style.color='red';
   var val =Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
   document.getElementById("securitycode").innerHTML =val;
   security.focus;
  }
  
 if( (name!="") && (email!="")  && (number!="") && (country!="") && (city!="") && (security!="") && (name.match(filt)) && (number.length==10) && (filter.test(email)) && (country.match(filt)) && (city.match(filt)) && (security == securitycode)) 
    {
     alert("ok");
          $('#submit_btn').val("Please wait");
     document.getElementById("form_id").submit();//submit() is a predefined function in js. 
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="formvali.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
 </head>
 <body onsubmit="loginload()">
 <div class="col-sm-12 content">
 <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
 <h2 class="text-center">
  Fill out this form and we will get back to you<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span>
 </h2>
 
 
   <!-- <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7245780.082381814!2d-88.29713116153964!3d27.53212533124578!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88c1766591562abf%3A0xf72e13d35bc74ed0!2sFlorida!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1470659148428" class="img-responsive" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 -->
 <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Bangalore Office</strong></h3>
  <iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=12.987510,77.620491 &z=13&output=embed" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
 <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Kerala Office</strong></h3>
 <iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=9.988126,76.295285 &z=13&output=embed" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
   </div>
 
 
 <div class="col-sm-6" style="line-height:1.45;">
  <h1 class="text-center contact">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact Us</h1>
  <form action="" method="POST" id="form_id" name="myform">
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
     <i id="nameerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
   
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>Mobile</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" id="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number">
     <i id="moberror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
   
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label style="margin-left:0px;">Email </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">  
     <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control"placeholder="Enter Your Email Id">
      <i id="emailerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
     
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>Country</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" id="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Country Name">
     <i id="countryerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
  
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>City</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control"placeholder="Enter Your City Name">
     <i id="cityerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div><br>
   
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
     <label>Query</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="query"placeholder="Enter Your Query here(optional)"></textarea>
     <i id="queryerror"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <span class="code"></strong>Security Code <span id="securitycode"></span></span>
     <input type="number" id="security" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the security code">
     <i id="codeerror"></i><br>
     <div class="form-group text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="sub" value="Submit" onclick="pagetest()" id="submit_btn"/>
      <button id="Button1" style="display:none;">Please wait..</button>
      
     </div>
      
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  <script>
   var val =Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
   document.getElementById("securitycode").innerHTML = val;
  </script>
  <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXRmYpTXDBP7vdQ-2fy11OqoKGUuGfcxI&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this method works fine.How can I validate this with the complete form?

Comment: Simply replace the form above and give an id to the submit button, which you can use later to change its value to please wait. Then copy your page_test() into mine and check.

Comment: Ya that will work but I need to check the email,number whether the input is filled with valid inputs or not.How can I check that using this method?

Comment: Ya its working but its not validating the regular expressions.Its just checking whether the field is empty or not.

Comment: Try to run to snippet. It is validating all the inputs and the regex too.

Comment: I tried by giving wrong inputs to name and country fields but button value gets changed without validating. :(

Comment: Actually the validation condition was missing in the final if, so now I have tested it again and works too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.Was checking that.Works prefect thanks a lot.You made my day and why the page gets loaded quickly.Can't I place the 'please wait..' value stand by?

Comment: Please upvote the answer so that it stays on top for anybody else with the same problem. What do you mean by 'stand by' bro? Please explain more.

Comment: Yes brother I have upvoted. If form is validated and button is clicked the form should submit and button value should still remain the same as "please wait..".Getting me?

Comment: Actually bro when a form is submitted the page refreshes in most cases, and so the html is loaded all over again. So you can't keep the value as please wait after submission :(

Comment: or else we can we have two buttons.Before submission second button is hidden and if the form is submitted first button should hide and second button should show.

Comment: Actually I don't know maybe then someone down the answer. Anyways. I think what you want is dynamic and it may need a server side language too.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `pagetest()` function with this function code below and check, I'm using jQuery call here after validation check:

```
function pagetest(){
    var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
        var filt =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if (!name.match(filt)){
            document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML='Name should not contain any number or special characters';
            document.getElementById("nameerror").style.color='red';
         }
        else{
            document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor="green";
            document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML='valid name';
            document.getElementById("nameerror").style.color='green';
        }

    var number=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
        if(number.length!=10)
          {
            document.getElementById("mobile").style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById("moberror").innerHTML="Number should be exactly 10 digits and not less than or more than that";
            document.getElementById("moberror").style.color='red';
          }
        else
          {
            document.getElementById("mobile").style.borderColor="green";
            document.getElementById("moberror").innerHTML="valid number";
            document.getElementById("moberror").style.color='green';
          }


    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})+$/;
        if (!filter.test(email)) {

            document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML="Please provide a valid email address";
            document.getElementById("emailerror").style.color="red";    
         }
        else{

            document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor="green";
            document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML='valid email address';
            document.getElementById("emailerror").style.color='green';
        }


    var country= document.getElementById("country").value;
        var filt =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if (!country.match(filt)) {
            document.getElementById("country").style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById("countryerror").innerHTML='country should not contain any number or special characters';
            document.getElementById("countryerror").style.color='red';
         }
        else{

            document.getElementById("country").style.borderColor="green";
            document.getElementById("countryerror").innerHTML='Valid Country name';
            document.getElementById("countryerror").style.color='green';
        }

    var city= document.getElementById("city").value;
        var filt =  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if (!city.match(filt)) {
            document.getElementById("city").style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById("cityerror").innerHTML='city should not contain any number or special characters';
            document.getElementById("cityerror").style.color='red';
         }
        else{
            document.getElementById("city").style.borderColor="green";
            document.getElementById("cityerror").innerHTML='Valid city name';
            document.getElementById("cityerror").style.color='green';
        }

            /*  var reg = /[^A-Za-z]/;
                if ((reg.test(query) == false) && (query ==""))
                {
                document.getElementById('query').style.borderColor="red";
                document.getElementById('queryerror').innerHTML="This field is required";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("query").style.borderColor="green";
                    document.getElementById("queryerror").innerHTML ="";
                }*/

    var security = document.getElementById("security").value;
    var securitycode = document.getElementById("securitycode").innerHTML;
        if(security ==securitycode){
            document.getElementById("security").style.borderColor="";
            document.getElementById("codeerror").innerHTML="Code matched";
            document.getElementById("codeerror").style.color='green';
        }   
        else{
            document.getElementById("security").style.borderColor="red";
            document.getElementById("codeerror").innerHTML="Code didn't match or emplty";
            document.getElementById("codeerror").style.color='red';
            var val =Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
            document.getElementById("securitycode").innerHTML =val;
            security.focus;
        }
        $('#Button1').hide();
        $('input[name=sub]').show();
        if( (name!="") && (email!="")  && (number!="") && (country!="") && (city!="") && (security!="")) 
        {
             $('#Button1').show();
             $('input[name=sub]').hide();
             // $('#form_id').submit(); //uncomment if want to submit after validation
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its working without validation.I am trying to get a solution with validation

Comment: have you fixed the validation issue? please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/rajender07/h2ut5dy1/4/  I've put it on fiddle for your testing only. Thanks :)

Comment: Its validating and button is changed but it's not checking the conditions of name,country and city. I've checked both in fiddle as well as in browser.:(

Comment: Its validating and now button is not changed.

Comment: But it is working fine at my end I just tested it https://jsfiddle.net/rajender07/h2ut5dy1/8/

Comment: But I'm the checking the fiddle as well as in browser.Everything works fine but button is not changed.

Comment: can you please send me screen shot of your browser with fiddle code having javascript only (full code screen) so I can compare against mine. Thanks

Comment: Here it is my complete code.
https://jsbin.com/wijanoj/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Sorry for delay, I checked your jsbin code, the problem is with jQuery which is not working, I checked the error and was of jQuery `$` is not defined that is why it's not working in jsbin.

Comment: Yes bro I have defined jQuery and checked it.It works fine but Form action is not performing. I've checked with browser.